# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod' from assembly 'mscorlib,

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When using

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(soapResponse);

it is not assigning value to obj.

It is working fine with xamarin android.but showing error for xamarin ios.

{System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator (System.Type createdType) [0x00000] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:685 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) [0x0008b] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:716 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00007] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:361 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00100] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:1013 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract (System.Type type) [0x0003e] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:242 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe (System.Type type) [0x0000b] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:130 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x0000e] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:138 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00047] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:710 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:689 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:846 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[Object] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:805 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[Object] (System.String value) [0x00000] in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:742 
  at TrxServices.Views.Login+d__21.MoveNext () [0x00372] in d:\DAta D Drive\SelfDemo\TrxServices\TrxServices\TrxServices\Views\Login.cs:300 }

Comment: iOS prohibits dynamic code generation, which limits the use of Reflection.Emit

Comment: This looks like you're deserializing the response from a login call to a server, what does your json look like? Is the `DeserializeObject` literally as it is in your code? Because it can probably benefit from a type argument... Share some code and data, not just the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

According to the Xamarin iOS limitations, this is not supported, as per Jason's comment :-

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/