# How to load a PDF stored as a Stream

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF document stored as a Stream object, and I am trying to load the data into a PDDocument. This seems like a straight forward task, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it without saving the stream locally first. Below is my code.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
     await _Results[0].FileData.CopyToAsync(stream);
     InputStream tempStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.ToArray());
     PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(tempStream);
     tempStream.close();
}
```

Here "_Results[0].FileData" is the pdf stored as a Stream and I know the data is correctly saved. The program crashed on the load line with the following.

[image]

Any insight on how to do this or where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: The error does not appear to be related to the way you are handling the binary content (stream), but rather that an assembly is not loaded as expected. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611050/system-typeloadexception-could-not-load-type-system-reflection-emit-dynamicmet and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932994/could-not-load-type-system-reflection-introspectionextensions-from-assembly-m

Comment: You shouldn't use PDFBox with IKVM. IKVM has been discontinued for years, and current PDFBox versions have never been built with IKVM.